# Ckeditor not Uploading Images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, blogs, minimagick

I'm using Ckeditor as my Rich-Text-Editor in my Rails application and I'm having trouble uploading images with it. For file upload support I'm using Carrier Wave and Minimagick. 
I'm not receiving any error whatsoever, the Ckeditor Editor just will not upload my image. Other than that, the Ckeditor Text Editor is working wonderfully.

ckeditor_attachment_file_uploader.rb:

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'carrierwave'

class CkeditorAttachmentFileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include Ckeditor::Backend::CarrierWave
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/ckeditor/attachments/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    Ckeditor.attachment_file_types
  end
end
```

ckeditor_image_uploader.rb:

```
class CkeditorPictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include Ckeditor::Backend::CarrierWave

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/ckeditor/pictures/#{model.id}"
  end

  process :extract_dimensions

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [118, 100]
  end

  version :content do
    process resize_to_limit: [800, 800]
  end

  def extension_white_list
    Ckeditor.image_file_types
  end
end
```

image_uploader.rb:

```
# encoding: utf-8

class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

end
```

If you need any for code to look at, let me know.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the web console? Any server logs when trying to upload?

Comment: All I seem to be getting is something saying, `Cannot render console`. This happens when I try to upload the image.